# Java Interfaces type declarations for methods

Tags: java, class, variables, interface

I have an interface which contains some arithmetic operations. I have created a class for complex numbers and it will implement the operations.

```
package numeric;
public interface Numeric {

    public void add();
    public void subtract();
    public void multiply();
}
```

My class looks something like this

```
package numeric;
public class Complex implements Numeric {

    private int Re, Im;
    public void add (Complex x){
        this.Re+=x.Re;
        this.Im+=x.Im;  
    }
}
```

My methods currently have no parameters in the interface as I do not know which type to make them because I have to use the same interface for fractions also. If I put `Complex` when I implement them in the class it will give an error saying that the class must implement all interface methods.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html). In the presented case `T extends Numeric<T>` seems fitting.

Comment: @Turing85 I must disagree. You can add an integer to a complex number, no?

Comment: @Bohemian you can still ad an `add(int real)` to `Complex`. But there are things I would classify as `Numeric` to which one normally cannot add an `int` (e.g. complex numbers in polar form).

Comment: Is it foreseen that a different type may be added? Eg a complex number added to a non-complex one? Also, consider immutability - that is, your methods could (or *should*, if best practises are followed) return new instances that are the result of the operation, rather than mutating the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach you can use is to force each `Numeric` sub-type convert to each other (a little like the `intValue`, `longValue`, `doubleValue`, etc. methods defined in `Number`, although the purpose is slightly different).

```
interface Numeric {
    public void add(Numeric other);

    public void subtract(Numeric other);

    public void multiply(Numeric other);

    public Complex toComplex();

    public Fraction toFraction();
}
```

This has cons and pros, one of the cons being that your interface is now bound to know all of its implementations (not sure what this is called, sealed types?)

The above can then be implemented as follows:

```
class Complex implements Numeric {

    private int Re, Im;

    @Override
    public void add(Numeric other) {
        Complex complex = other.toComplex();
        this.Re += complex.Re;
        this.Im += complex.Im;
    }

    @Override
    public void subtract(Numeric other) {
        Complex complex = other.toComplex();
        this.Re -= complex.Re;
        this.Im -= complex.Im;
    }

    @Override
    public Complex toComplex() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Fraction toFraction() {
        //convert to fraction
        return null;
    }
    //rest of the implementation
}
```

---

Just a side note: typically, such APIs encourage immutability of data structures, so it would be advisable to change it to something like:

```
interface Numeric {
    public Numeric add(Numeric other);

    public Numeric subtract(Numeric other);

    public Numeric multiply(Numeric other);

    public Complex toComplex();

    public Fraction toFraction();
}
```

And

```
class Complex implements Numeric {

    private final int re, im;

    public Complex(int re, int im) {
        this.re = re;
        this.im = im;
    }

    @Override
    public Numeric add(Numeric other) {
        Complex complex = other.toComplex();
        return new Complex(this.re + complex.re, this.im + complex.im);
    }

    @Override
    public Numeric subtract(Numeric other) {
        Complex complex = other.toComplex();
        return new Complex(this.re - complex.re, this.im - complex.im);
    }

    @Override
    public Complex toComplex() {
        return this;
    }

    @Override
    public Fraction toFraction() {
        //convert to fraction
        return null;
    }

    //rest of the implementation
}
```